Can we ever have $\log_a(b) = \log_c(d)$ where the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ is pairwise coprime?
I'm working on a number-theoretic problem and have shown that something interesting would follow if this never happened. None of the basic logarithmic manipulations I've tried so far have been successful. I'm aware that there are some very deep results about linear independence of logarithmic forms but at first glance this seems to be a much simpler problem. I'm not at all convinced that this calls for any heavy machinery, but I might be mistaken.
Can we ever have $\log_a(b) = \log_c(d)$ where the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$ is pairwise coprime?

Not at all.    $\log_a b=\log_{a^2}b^2$. And so on.  Did you mean to impose other conditions?

@lulu Sorry, I did not think of that case. I've edited the question to hopefully avoid trivial cases.

This is equivalent to $\log(b)\log(c)=\log(a)\log(d)$ having no "nontrivial" solutions. I think this is unsolved, but I don't have a reference offhand. There's some discussion about the linear independence of numbers of the form $\log(u)\log(v)$ for rational $u,v$ in recent work of Calegari, Dimitrov, and Tang; some of the references there might be helpful.

It feels like the answer to OP's question should be "no".

Is this a discrete log or what?

@CarlSchildkraut Thanks so much for the reference :) Did not expect this to be unsolved!
